# FFMPEG - What is the difference or relationship between -rtbufsize and -thread_queue_size?

Tags: ffmpeg

Recording my desktop with ffmpeg (specially on Windows, less on Linux) I meet situations where/when ffmpeg complains about real time buffer size or thread queue size.
I understand that the queue size is the number of frames that can reside in the queue and thus I am incited to think that it increases the buffer size as well.
Can someone clarify these notions to me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thread_queue_size` is applicable to all inputs and determines how many packets from that input can be queued at the application-level while waiting for ffmpeg to accept and process it in its main thread.

`rtbufsize` is used by a handful of capture devices (mostly `dshow`) to hold incoming frames while waiting for them to be transferred to the application-level queue for that input.

Neither option will adjust the value of the other, and you should set them both manually.